# Dynamically update openpyxl generated charts when sorting columns

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl 2.4.8 to generate some excel files. I fill in some data into some columns and insert a chart that plots that data. If I do so manually in excel the charts dynamically update if I use the data-sort methods to remove datapoints. However, the openpyxl generated chart is static and ignore any such sorting.
When looking at the xml of a chart generate by excel and of the one generated by openpyxl I see a lot of differences (fx. all tags are prefaced by 'c:' in excel), but nothing that looks like a setting which would automatically update the content. I cannot find a setting in excel that would turn this on or off either.
The code I use to generate an excel file with a chart is here:

```
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import *
from random import random
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.chart import (
    LineChart,
    BarChart,
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)
from openpyxl.drawing.text import CharacterProperties

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.title = 'interactiveChart'

num = 9

ws.cell(column=1, row=2, value='X')
ws.cell(column=2, row=2, value='Y')
for i in range(num+1):
    ws.cell(column=1, row=3+i, value=random()*100)
    ws.cell(column=2, row=3+i, value='=A{0}*3+4+ABS(5/(11-A{0}))+ABS(10/(35-    A{0}))+ABS(30/(67-A{0}))'.format(3+i))

textSize = 10
modeChart = ScatterChart()
modeChart.title = 'Resonance'
modeChart.title.tx.rich.p[0].r.rPr = CharacterProperties(sz=textSize*100,     b=True)
modeChart.style = 48
modeChart.x_axis.title = "X"
modeChart.x_axis.title.tx.rich.p[0].r.rPr =     CharacterProperties(sz=textSize*100, b=True)
modeChart.y_axis.title = "Y"
modeChart.y_axis.title.tx.rich.p[0].r.rPr = CharacterProperties(sz=textSize*100, b=True)
modeChart.legend = None

xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=num+3)
yvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_row=num+3)
series = Series(yvalues, xvalues, title_from_data=False, title='Resonace')
modeChart.series.append(series)
s1 = modeChart.series[0]
s1.marker.symbol = "diamond"
s1.marker.graphicalProperties.solidFill = "6495ED"
s1.marker.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "6495ED"
s1.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True

modeChart.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low"
modeChart.y_axis.tickLblPos = "low"

modeChart.width = 12
modeChart.height = 7
ws.add_chart(modeChart, "F6")

ws.auto_filter.ref = 'A2:B{}'.format(num+3)

ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet")
wb.remove_sheet(ws)
wb.save('aTest.xlsx')
```

I can't find a reference to this behavior so I'm not certain what I should be looking for either.

Comment: Add your `openpyxl` Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There is a tag in the xml of Excel charts called: `<plotVisOnly/>`. This tag was added in openpyxl 2.5 (see the bitbucket issue: [Setting property plotVisOnly for charts](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/828/setting-property-plotvisonly-for-charts)).
Thanks to a [friendly openpyxl contributor](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/884/sorted-columns-and-scatter-charts-not) for helping me solve this.
In order to make this work with my anaconda installation I first removed openpyxl:

```
pip uninstall openpyxl
```

Then i downloaded the latest openpyxl version (>2.5) from [python.org package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl), unzipped it and ran:

```
python setup.py install
```

This installed the >2.5 version of openpyxl. I double checked this in python by running:

```
import openpyxl
openpyxl.__version__
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done directly in openpyxl.

openpyxl is a file format library and not a replacement for Excel. Filtering and sorting needs to be done by an application such as Excel, openpyxl just maintains the relevant metadata.

Comment: I'm not trying to filter or sort the data with openpyxl. I'm creating the Excel files with openpyxl and opening them in Excel. I am then using Excel to filter and sort the data. If I created a chart in excel this chart would update when the data is filtered, but charts created with openpyxl do not update when I use Excel to filter the data.

Comment: Can't really comment on what Excel does but I would expect the chart to update to reflect changes in the data, it does in my charts.